# force linear regression to intercept with x axis

Tags: r, regression

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpLag.png)I am really new at R and have been researching this for quite a while now, but it just doesn't work. I have a plot through which I have fitted a linear regression, now I want to force the regression to go through a specific point on the x-axis (2;0).

This is the formula I used:

```
abline(lm(I(H2S.Basaltsite-0) ~ I(t.Basaltsite-2) + 0, data=values), col="red")
```

unfortunately, it doesn't work. Any ideas why?

[image]

Thats the plot I get with your solution, Ben..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `abline` just can't handle this case.

```
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(x=runif(100,0,10))
dd$y <- rnorm(100,mean=1+2*dd$x,sd=0.5)
m1 <- lm(y~I(x-2)+0,dd)
plot(y~x,data=dd,ylim=c(0,25),las=1,bty="l")
b <- coef(m1)[1]
curve(b*(x-2),add=TRUE,col=2)
points(2,0,pch=16)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Ben, 
thank you so much for your help! I have to admit that I don't fully understand your solution though, especially the dd$y step. I tried to apply this to the dataset I have, but I feel like the regression I end up with is not very accurate anymore, is this just the price I pay for fixing the intercept or is there still a mistake?